# Защита данных при ajax-запросе

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Всем привет, пытаюсь реализовать ajax-запрос и получить ответ с сервера, используя XMLHttpRequest.

На сайте (wordpress) существует страница: https:/example.com/entries/, доступ к которой имеют только админы сайта, на этой странице должны отображаться некоторые данные в отсортированном виде.

Существует файл function.js, который запускается только на странице https:/example.com/entries/. В этом файле и осуществляется ajax-запрос методом XMLHttpRequest к серверу: xhr.open('GET', upload.php), сервер возвращает объект с приватными данными.

В файле upload.php выполняется скрипт, генерирующий объект с приватными данными, но по идее к этому файлу может кто-то обратиться и взять оттуда данные (зная расположение этого файла или еще может как-то)

Вопросы:

1. т.к. function.js запускается только на странице https:/example.com/entries/, к которой имеют доступ только админы, значит ли это, что код в function.js защищен от посторонних глаз?
2. можно ли сделать так, чтобы никто не мог обратиться к файлу upload.php, даже зная, где он лежит?
3. вообще, интересует вопрос по поводу защиты данных в этом сценарии, по возможности не сильно сложным способом.

Comment: Логин/пароль в ВордПрессе вроде есть. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, не понимаю, о чем вы? Я же написал, что доступ к странице https:/example.com/entries/, имеют только админы (это значит, что они уже вошли через логин и пароль), а вот файл upload.php - это не страница, а сценарий, значит доступ к нему только для админов я сделать не могу.

Comment: Что значит "не могу"? А в чем смысл вопроса тогда? "У меня сарай с дровами, как его закрыть от воров? Дверь с замком поставить не могу". Ну если не можете, то на нет и суда нет - "нету ножек - нет и варенья".

Comment: КТО, КТО ПОСТАВИЛ этому вопросу +1?! В ЧЕМ ЕГО ЦЕННОСТЬ?

Comment: И при чем здесь аякс вообще если вопрос в защите upload.php?

Comment: @Ипатьев, я описал ситуацию в целом, чтобы было понимание. Я не знаю, какой из аспектов данного вопроса является несущественным, поэтому старался задать вопрос максимально понятно.

Comment: В общем гуглите, как использовать авторизацию вордпресса в своих "сценариях". Это единственный осмысленный вариант решения проблемы. При любых других способах "закрыть" upload.php, доступ к этому файлу, *разумеется*, потеряют и админы.

Comment: @Ипатьев, Что значит "не могу"? Это значит, что не знаю каким образом.

Comment: Ну тогда этот вопрос и надо, наверное, задавать? Причем желательно сразу в поиск. Умение формулировать проблему для программиста куда важнее чем умение писать код

Comment: Вот я за вас нагуглил. три строчки: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956468/285587 только путь к wp_load надо указать правильно

Comment: Вам надо осознать что нет никакой разницы между «страницей» и «сценарием»

Comment: @AlexeyTen я думаю что под страницей имеется в виду то что добавляется через админку. А "сценарий" - это отдельный пхп скрипт